# How to center/justify text/icon button in Bootstrap collapsed header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have some jQuery mobile pages with header containing text and/or buttons.  Sometimes there are centered text, others just crowded with buttons.  There are several of screen sizes and/or number of buttons.

[image: header with buttons and text]

How do I duplicate this in Bootstrap collapsed navbar-header?  I created this jsfiddle sample, but couldn't figure out how to center/justify text and buttons.

[Jsfiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/whoever/aoyss2Lm/1/)

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<!-- button left -->
<a type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left navbar-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"> 
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</a> 

<!-- button right --->
<a class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-icon" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
</a>

<!-- in the middle -->
<div style="text-align:center">
<a class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-icon" data-toggle="collaplse">
    <i class="fa fa-reply fa-2x"></i>
</a>
 <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-icon" data-toggle="collaplse">
    <i class="fa fa-foward fa-2x"></i>
</a>
 <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-icon" data-toggle="collaplse">
    Some Text
</a>
</div>
</div>

<style>
body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
.navbar-header .navbar-icon {
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:0;
}

.navbar-header  a.navbar-icon {
    padding:0 0px;
}
</style>
```

The closest answer I can find is [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967280/show-icons-in-the-collapsed-navbar-in-bootstrap-3).  Tried the answers there, didn't work.

Any hint what I miss?  Thanks

Update: [Final version](http://jsfiddle.net/whoever/aoyss2Lm/11/) based on suggestions.  Probably something to do with customized bootstrap, my local version looks a lot better than on jsfiddle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not able to center your icons is because they have a css property that is making them float right;

add a class to the icons for example 'no-float' then add this to your css
`.no-float { float:none!important; }`

that will make it work

So this 
`<a class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-icon" data-toggle="collaplse">`
becomes this
`<a class="no-float navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-icon" data-toggle="collaplse">`

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/aoyss2Lm/6/

I added the bootstrap class "text-only" inline to the `<li>`

Comment: My first time using jsfiddle, must have done something wrong.  Couldn't see your change or any effect.  Carlos's no float worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @Whoever just click the link in my answer and it will take you to the jsfiddle that I updated. Click the drop down link in the code preview area (bottom right window) and you will see the text is centered.

Comment: I see.  A little misunderstanding.  I was trying to squeeze in more buttons to the collapsed navbar-header area for user interactions in mobile view.  Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/whoever/aoyss2Lm/7   Now I just need to tidy up the stylesheet.  Thanks for your help.